# C++ : terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' while computing length of big strings

Tags: c++, memory, bad-alloc

In the following code I'm trying to count the number of a's in the input string s, repeating the string(if needed) upto n places where 0 < n < 10^(12). My code works for small values of n but it gives std::bad_alloc() for large values of n. Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


int main(){
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    long n;
    cin >> n;
    long len = s.length();
    long ans = 0;
    if(n <= len){
        for(long i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if(s[i] == 'a'){
                ans++;
            }   
        }
    }
    else{
        string comp = s;
        while(comp.length() < n){
            comp += s;
        }
        long diff = comp.length() - n;
        if(diff > 0){
            while (diff == 0){
                comp.pop_back();
                diff = comp.length() - n;
            }
        }
        for(long i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if(comp[i] == 'a'){
                ans++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << ans << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `10^12` bytes is 1 TB, guess why you are getting a `std::bad_alloc`..

Comment: `10^12` would use **a lot** of memory. Unless you have something like a fully configured IBM mainframe, that amount of RAM is unlikely.

Comment: but i am using `long`

Comment: you are using a `long` to store the length, but you are using a `std::string` to store the string itself which is allocated on heap.

Comment: can `std::string` store such a long string? or maybe i should look for an alternative solution to the problem if it cant

Comment: Do you have that much memory in your computer?

Comment: @RichardCritten i am running it on an online judge compiler

Comment: the amount that can be stored by a std::string doesn't depend on the implementation but on the underlying memory amount, since it will use `std::malloc` and `std::free` (or `new` / `delete`)

Comment: If you're going to create a string with terabyte characters, you need a terabyte of RAM. Full stop. The string does not exist in hyperspace. There is no warp drive to take the string into some other dimension. Anything that's stored in a string gets stored in actual memory. Additionally, what exactly do you expect to accomplish by: `if(diff > 0){ while (diff == 0){`. In which situation do you actually expect the while loop to execute? How do you expect to arrive at a situation where `diff` is greater than 0, but then magically becomes equal to 0?

Comment: Given your description, why all of this code to do something very simple?  `auto n = std::count(s.begin(), s.end(), 'a');` and then `std::string test(n, 'a');`.  Even given the issues with the memory allocation, that is a lot of code for something that can be done in two or three 3 lines of C++.

Answer (score 1):

10^12 is a huge number. Even if every item takes a 1 byte, you would need 1 TB of memory.

Let's change the strategy. Check it out the next example:

> instance

For n = word.size(), this will return 1.

If n = 2*word.size():

> instanceinstance

This will return 2:

For n = 3*word.size():

> instanceinstanceinstance

This will return 3:

See the pattern here? You could take the result with a simple multiplication, at take the rest with a simple loop:

```
std::string name;
std::cin >> name;

int n;
std::cin >> n;

int multiplier = std::count(name.begin(),name.end(),'a');

int full_iterations = n / name.size();
int last_iteration = n % name.size();

int ocurrences = multiplier * full_iterations * std::count(name.begin(),name.begin() + last_iteration,'a');

std::cout << ocurrences << std::endl;
```

Documentation of std::count [right here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count/)